# Backfilling 6 million records in Ruby on Rails using migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have three tables in PostgreSQL: SKU, Product and ProductHistory. I added a new column, `price`, to the ProductHistory table, and need to backfill data on that column based on the `price` column in SKU. Here is their relationship:

[image: data relationship]

A SKU has many Products, and each Product has many ProductHistories. But the `price` attribute is only available on SKU, not on Product. I have to somehow pass it to ProductHistory.

I tried running the code below in the rails console, but this script is super inefficient since I have over 6 million records to backfill. It ran many hours and still didn't finish, so I killed the process.

```
// Find all SKU ids and prices
@all_SKU_array = SKU.all.pluck(:id, :price)

@all_SKU_array.each do |sku|
  @sku_id = sku[0]
  @sku_price = sku[1]

  // Find all Products that belong to that SKU
  @all_products = SKU.find(@sku_id).products

  // Find all product histories of each product
  // I flatten them because some products do not have any product histories, all we need is just the ids. All products that belong to the same SKU have the same price.
  @all_product_histories = @all_products.map { |p| p.product_history_ids }.flatten(1)

  // Update the price
  @all_product_histories.map do |ph_id| 
     PH.find(ph_id).update_attributes!(:price => @productPrice)
   end
end
```

Should I use a rails migration to update the data? How can I join SKU and Product so that passing the `price` attribute to ProductHistory is easier?

Furthermore, I am updating 6 million rows of data. I am planning to use `self.up` and `self.down` to roll back if anything goes wrong. Right now, the default value of "price" on ProductHistory is nil, so I'd probably just reset them back to nil if something is wrong, but I'd appreciate any solution that the community recommends.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to write a raw sql query for this. For ex:

```
UPDATE product_histories
SET product_histories.price = skus.price
FROM product_histories
INNER JOIN products ON products.id = product_histories.product_id
INNER JOIN skus ON skus.id = products.sku_id
```

Now there are multiple ways to execute this query, one of them being:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("#{query_written_above}")
```

This should definitely speed up the process.

Solution provided by AbM also looks good.

Comment: A raw query is best for updating millions of records, but I would wrap a `find_in_batches` around this, so it processes something like 10K or 100K records at a time, which is safer as you can see it make progress and resume if there's any error. It also means you can take it a step further and process multiple batches simultaneously using Parallel gem, Sidekiq, or other techniques.

Comment: Totally agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Your backfilling is quite inefficient. But even with improvement, you shouldn't run the backfilling in a migration. [You can read a bit more here on how to best backfill data](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations#backfilling-data).

Now onto your code, I am assuming that this is how your models look like:

```
class SKU < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :product_histories, through: :products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_histories
end
```

You backfilling logic could be:

```
# use find_each instead of each to not load everything in memory
SKU.find_each do |sku|
  sku.product_histories.update_all(price: sku.price)
end
```